# Transfer file to a ftp server using SQL Server script

Tags: sql-server, ftp, sftp

I want to generate a file, using SQL Server script, and then transfer that file to a ftp server.

The following script works very well when the encryption configured is "use plain ftp". Unfortunately the same script don't work if the encryption is "require explicit ftp over TLS".

Can anyone know how can I modified the script (what should I add) to let it work?

Thanks in advance

```
declare @bcpcmd varchar (4000), @file varchar( 20)

set @file = 'File_' +  cast (year( getdate()) as varchar ) + '_'+   right('0' + cast(month (getdate()) as varchar),2 )+  '_' +  right('0'+ cast( day(getdate ()) as varchar),2 ) + '_' + right('0' + cast(datepart (Hour, getdate()) as varchar ),2)+ '_' + right('0' + cast (datepart( minute,getdate ()) as varchar), 2)

set @bcpcmd = 'bcp "select * from mydb.dbo.customer" queryout C:\Web\'+@file+ '.csv'+' -t^; -T -c'

EXEC master ..xp_cmdshell @bcpcmd

DECLARE @FTPServer varchar (128)
DECLARE @FTPUser varchar (128)
DECLARE @FTPPwd varchar (128)
DECLARE @SourcePath varchar (128)
DECLARE @SourceFiles varchar (128)
DECLARE @DestPath varchar (128)
DECLARE @FTPMode varchar (10)

-- FTP attributes.
SET @FTPServer = 'ftp.xxxx.com'
SET @FTPUser = 'myLogin'
SET @FTPPwd = 'myPwd'
SET @SourcePath = 'C:\Web'
SET @SourceFiles = @file+'.csv'
SET @DestPath = 'Sources' -- Destination path. Blank for root directory.
SET @FTPMode = 'binary' -- ascii, binary or blank for default.

DECLARE @cmd varchar (1000)
DECLARE @workfile varchar (128)
DECLARE @nowstr varchar (25)

-- Get the %TEMP% environment variable.
DECLARE @tempdir varchar (128)
CREATE TABLE #tempvartable(info VARCHAR(1000 ))
INSERT #tempvartable EXEC master.. xp_cmdshell 'echo %temp%'
SET @tempdir = (SELECT top 1 info FROM #tempvartable)
IF RIGHT( @tempdir, 1 ) <> '\' SET @tempdir = @tempdir + '\'
DROP TABLE #tempvartable

-- Generate @workfile
SET @nowstr = replace( replace(convert (varchar( 30), GETDATE(), 121 ), ' ' , '_' ), ':', '-')
SET @workfile = 'FTP_SPID' + convert (varchar( 128), @@spid) + '_' + @nowstr + '.txt'

-- Deal with special chars for echo commands.
select @FTPServer = replace( replace(replace (@FTPServer, '|', '^|'),'<' ,'^<'), '>','^>' )
select @FTPUser = replace( replace(replace (@FTPUser, '|', '^|'), '<','^<' ),'>', '^>')
select @FTPPwd = replace( replace(replace (@FTPPwd, '|', '^|'), '<','^<' ),'>', '^>')
select @DestPath = replace( replace(replace (@DestPath, '|', '^|'),'<' ,'^<'), '>','^>' )
IF RIGHT( @SourcePath, 1 ) <> '\' SET @SourcePath = @SourcePath + '\'

-- Build the FTP script file.
select @cmd = 'echo ' + 'open ' + @FTPServer + ' > ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master ..xp_cmdshell @cmd
select @cmd = 'echo ' + @FTPUser + '>> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master ..xp_cmdshell @cmd
select @cmd = 'echo ' + @FTPPwd + '>> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master ..xp_cmdshell @cmd
select @cmd = 'echo ' + 'prompt ' + ' >> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master ..xp_cmdshell @cmd
IF LEN (@FTPMode) > 0
BEGIN
       select @cmd = 'echo ' + @FTPMode + ' >> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
       EXEC master ..xp_cmdshell @cmd
END
IF LEN (@DestPath) > 0
BEGIN
       select @cmd = 'echo ' + 'cd ' + @DestPath + ' >> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
       EXEC master ..xp_cmdshell @cmd
END
select @cmd = 'echo ' + 'put ' + @SourcePath + @SourceFiles + ' >> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master ..xp_cmdshell @cmd
select @cmd = 'echo ' + 'quit' + ' >> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master ..xp_cmdshell @cmd

-- Execute the FTP command via script file.
select @cmd = 'ftp -s:' + @tempdir + @workfile
create table #a ( id int identity(1 ,1), s varchar( 1000))
insert #a
EXEC master ..xp_cmdshell @cmd
select id, ouputtmp = s from #a

-- Clean up.
drop table #a
select @cmd = 'del ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master ..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the Windows ftp.exe, which doesn't support FTPS.  I think [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftps) includes a command-line version that does support FTPS.